Is there any way to access activity context inside a VisionCamera FrameProcessorPlugin class without having to wrap it in a view?
I've been recently migrating an old clunky handlandmark-based application to use VisionCamera's frameprocessors, and to instantiate mediapipe's handlandmark i need activty context as a parameter
Using the plugin builder gives me a pre-made class for the plugin and one for the package. Thing is i can't find much online about those classes and file structure to mess around with it, everything i try to do breaks the build.
The files made by the plugin builder are:
Plugin:
class HandLandmarkProcessorPlugin(proxy: VisionCameraProxy, options: Map<String, Any>?): FrameProcessorPlugin() {
  
  
  override fun callback(frame: Frame, arguments: Map<String, Any>?): Any? {
    // code goes here
}
}

(i've omitted the handlandmarker processing code)
Package:
class HandLandmarkProcessorPluginPackage : ReactPackage {
  companion object {
    init {
      FrameProcessorPluginRegistry.addFrameProcessorPlugin("handLandmark") { proxy, options ->
        HandLandmarkProcessorPlugin(proxy, options)
      }
    }
  }

  override fun createNativeModules(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext): List<NativeModule> {
    return emptyList()
  }

  override fun createViewManagers(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext): List<ViewManager<*, *>> {
    return emptyList()
  }
}

Is there a way to access the context reference inside the plugin class?
the plugin is registered in MainApplication.kt that is called by MainActivity.kt
I've tried a few things to get context reference inside the plugin class ( searching around i found a few things i could invoke such as context, activity!!.applicationContext!!, importing mainActivity, importing mainApplication) I've been searching about it for a few days, but i can't seem to build it no matter what i try
